# Date is saving one day less in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, momentjs

I'm using react widget date picker. (https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/datetime-picker?_k=c0gioy)

I'm passing date in this format : Sat Jul 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

I'm using laravel in server side.

But date is saving one day less. It's saving as 2017-07-14 in database.

Can anyone please tell me the reason ?

Thank you.

Comment: Sat Jul 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) is equal to Fri Jul 14 2017 18:30:00 GMT. It might be that the server is operating in GMT.

Comment: In server timezone is in 'Asia/Kolkata'

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, set an `env` variable called `APP_TIMEZONE` with whatever timezone you want it to use

if you are dealing with database timezone, add `DB_TIMEZONE` in `.env` file and set its value to the timezone you want

**EDIT**

the backup solution (if none was found), would be to create a custom function that calculates the offset between the client timezone and the server timezone. then use it to save the appropriate date to the database.

an example:

```
function date_default_timezone_offset_get()
{
    $offset = timezone_offset_get(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()), new \DateTime());
    return sprintf("%s%02d:%02d", ($offset >= 0) ? '+' : '-', abs($offset / 3600), abs($offset % 3600));
}
```

Comment: I have set APP_TIMEZONE to 'Asia/Kolkata'. Even though date is saving one day off.

Comment: what about `DB_TIMEZONE`?

Comment: still same issue